# scrapy get a tag thanks to the precedent tag

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

hello I have this html script:

```
<div class="sc-grid-col-12">
    <div class="cldt-categorized-data cldt-data-section sc-pull-right">
        <dl>
            <dt>Nr. of Doors</dt>
            <dd>5</dd>
            <dt>Nr.of seat</dt>
            <dd>5</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
```

And I would like  to get the dd value (5) based on the dt value Nr. of Doors.

this the code that I am using (which is wrong):

```
    start_urls = ["https://www.autoscout24.com/offers/peugeot-107-active-1hand-led-scheckheftgepflegt-tuev-au-neu-gasoline-silver-2c985ebc-5a39-4d12-bd50-605f7e9b4b58?cldtidx=13"]
    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.sc-grid-col-12'):
            yield {
                'portes': quote.xpath("//div[@class='cldt-categorized-data cldt-data-section sc-pull-right']//dl[dt='Nr. of Doors']//following-sibling::dd").extract(),
                  }
```

Below the output that I get:

```
{'portes': ['<dd>\n<a href="/lst/peugeot">Peugeot</a>\n</dd>', '<dd>\n<a href="/lst/peugeot/107">107</a>\n</dd>', '<dd>\nSilver\n</dd>', '<dd>\nMetallic\n</dd>', '<dd>\nCloth, Grey\n</dd>', '<dd>\nCompact\n</dd>', '<dd>\n3\n</dd>', '<dd>\n4\n</dd>', '<dd>\n3003/ACR\n</dd>']}
```

this result is duplicated a lot of time!!

Comment: I solve the last problem of duplicate value, but I have always a wrong output:

      'portes': []}

Comment: @Anna, Thanks for your help, sadly the code doesn't work, so I continued to search on the side of xpath and after lot of search, I discovered my problem is due to the dot(.) in 'Nr. of Doors' so I have to escape it in my xpath. please can u tell me how can I escape it?

Comment: I almost reach my result, here the xpath that I am using : 'portes': quote.xpath("//dl/dt[contains(normalize-space(.), 'Doors')]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()").extract()  I get this output ['\n3\n'] But I don't know how can I remove \n!!!  any help is welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.sc-grid-col-12'):
            yield {
                'portes' = unidecode.unidecode(
        re.sub(r'\s+',' ',quote.css("div.cldt-categorized-data.cldt-data-section.sc-pull-right dl[dt='Nr. of Doors'] + dd::text").extract_first()))
            }
```